# Dailogflow agent gets and tells data of mysql database

Tags: node.js, artificial-intelligence, webhooks, dialogflow-es, agent

First of all thanks a lot for this amazing community.
I have to tell that i am very new to programming (i am more of a statistician) but up to now it seems very challenging and fun!
Lately I have been challenging myself trying to create Dialogflow agent that retrieves data from a database when asked. I am using node.js.
Of course, in order to build I am trying to see codes on the internet and coherently modify them to my needs but since three days I am stuck!

I can't figure what is the problem, please helppp!!!1

Find below my code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require( 'firebase-functions' );
const mysql = require( 'mysql' );
const {WebhookClient} = require( 'dialogflow-fulfillment' );
const {Text, Card, Image, Suggestion, Payload} = require( 'dialogflow-fulfillment' );

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

// Wikipedia link and image URLs
const mysiteurl = 'site URL';


exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest( ( request, response ) =>{
  const agent = new WebhookClient( {request, response} );
  console.log( 'Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify( request.headers ) );
  console.log( 'Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify( request.body ) );

  function welcome( agent ){
    agent.add( `Welcome to infohub personal assistant, my name is Isobel` );
    agent.add( new Card( {
        title: `mysite`,
        imageUrl: mysiteurl,
        text: `Did you know already mysite if not visit it now! `,
        buttonText: 'mysite',
        buttonUrl: mysiteurl
      } )
    );
    agent.add( `I can help you get information already contained in mysite` );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `population` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `avgincome` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `thisyeargdp` ) );
  }

  function getinfo( agent ){
    // Get parameters from Dialogflow to convert
    const country = agent.parameters.country;
    const info = agent.parameters.info;
    console.log( `User requested to get info on  ${info} in ${country}` );


    if( action === 'get.data' ){

      //Call the callDBJokes method
      output = callDB().then( ( output ) =>{
        // Return the results of the weather API to API.AI
        response.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
        response.send( JSON.stringify( output ) );
      } ).catch( ( error ) =>{
        // If there is an error let the user know
        response.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
        response.send( JSON.stringify( error ) );
      } );

    }


    // Sent the context to store the parameter information
    // and make sure the followup 
    agent.setContext( {
      name: 'info',
      lifespan: 1,
      parameters: {country: country, info: info}
    } );

    // Compile and send response
    agent.add( ` ${info} in ${country} is ${output}` );

    agent.add( `Would you like to know something else?` );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `population` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `avgincome` ) );
    agent.add( new Suggestion( `thisyeargdp` ) );
  }


  function fallback( agent ){
    agent.add( `I didn't get that, can you try again?` );
  }

  function callDB( info, country ){
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>{

        try{

          var connection = mysql.createConnection( {
            host: "sql7.freemysqlhosting.net",
            user: "sql7243950",
            password: "XXXXXXXX",
            database: "sql7243950"
          } );


          connection.query( 'SELECT' + info + 'FROM mocktable WHERE country=' + country, function( error, results, fields ){
            if( !error ){

              let response = "The solution is: " + results[0];
              response = response.toString();
              let output = {'speech': response, 'displayText': response};
              console.log( output );
              resolve( output );

            } else{

              let output = {
                'speech': 'Error. Query Failed.',
                'displayText': 'Error. Query Failed.'
              };
              console.log( output );
              reject( output );

            }
          } );
          connection.end();

        } catch
          ( err ){
          let output = {
            'speech': 'try-cacth block error',
            'displayText': 'try-cacth block error'
          };
          console.log( output );
          reject( output );

        }

      }
    )
      ;
  }


  let intentMap = new Map(); // Map functions to Dialogflow intent names
  intentMap.set( 'Default Welcome Intent', welcome );
  intentMap.set( 'get info about mycountry', getinfo );
  intentMap.set( 'Default Fallback Intent', fallback );
  agent.handleRequest( intentMap );
} )
;
```

Comment: I messed the indentation when posting but that is fine in the real code

Comment: You don't indicate what errors or problems you're having, but I noticed when trying to format your code that all of the "=>" you had written as "= >" with a space in between, which is a syntax error. I've corrected that in my reformatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here, some related and some not. Let's go through some of them.

For starters, you have a comparison

```
if( action === 'get.data' ){
```

but 'action' isn't defined or assigned anywhere. So this block will never be executed (and never call the database, it looks like).

It isn't clear how you're doing some of the assignments. When you're getting the output of the query, your line is

```
output = callDB().then( ( output ) =>{
```

which appears to be mixing getting a Promise back and trying to use the result of Promise completion. I suspect that the second "output" is what you want and not the first, for reasons that I hope are a little clearer in a bit.

In that `then()` clause, you're sending back JSON, but then also (outside of the `then()` clause) trying to use the Dialogflow library to set a context, set a reply, and provide suggestion chips. Mixing these two methods doesn't work - either send JSON or use the library.

This is compounded since `callDB()` (which you call before the `then()`) generates JSON to be sent back. Again - pick one method or the other. I suspect the better approach will be to have `callDB()` actually call the DB and possibly massage and return a Promise with the results for the calling method to format into what you want the user to hear/see.

Speaking of Promises, it is **good** that `callDB()` returns a Promise. However, you're not treating that promise correctly in two ways:

First, since `getInfo()` calls things that run asynchronously (ie - the call to `callDB()`) it must return a Promise as well. This is why you probably didn't want to capture the result from `callDB()` as I noted above. The easiest way to do this is for your code to do something like

```
return callDB().then( output => {
  // Output things are fine.
}).catch( err => {
  // Output the world is ending.
};
```

The second problem with how you deal with Promises is that your current implementation of `getInfo()` has code *after* this block. This, currently, is where you do all the `agent.setContext()` and `agent.add()` calls. Those *must* be inside the `then()` block. (Where my "things are fine" comment is above.)